# How to make audio sound better? (C + FFMpeg audio generation example)

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, wave

So I found this great C FFMpeg official [example](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html) which I simplified:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#undef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#endif

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil/mathematics.h"

#define INBUF_SIZE 4096
#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096

/*
 * Audio encoding example
 */
static void audio_encode_example(const char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int frame_size, i, j, out_size, outbuf_size;
    FILE *f;
    short *samples;
    float t, tincr;
    uint8_t *outbuf;

    printf("Audio encoding\n");

    /* find the MP2 encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MP2);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c= avcodec_alloc_context();

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 64000;
    c->sample_rate = 44100;
    c->channels = 2;

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* the codec gives us the frame size, in samples */
    frame_size = c->frame_size;
    samples = malloc(frame_size * 2 * c->channels);
    outbuf_size = 10000;
    outbuf = malloc(outbuf_size);

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode a single tone sound */
    t = 0;
    tincr = 2 * M_PI * 440.0 / c->sample_rate;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<frame_size;j++) {
            samples[2*j] = (int)(sin(t) * 10000);
            samples[2*j+1] = samples[2*j];
            t += tincr;
        }
        /* encode the samples */
        out_size = avcodec_encode_audio(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, samples);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(outbuf);
    free(samples);

    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    /* must be called before using avcodec lib */
    avcodec_init();

    /* register all the codecs */
    avcodec_register_all();

    audio_encode_example("test.mp2");

    return 0;
}
```

How should it sound like? May be I don't get something but it sounds awful =( how to make audio generation sound better/ more interesting/ melodical in a wary shourt way (no special functions just how to change this code to make it sound better)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, it should be a pure tone, or an ascending tone (I'm really not sure).  Either way it probably won't sound very nice.  We rarely hear pure sine wave tones in nature - they sound rather strident and harsh.  Most things that we consider to sound "musical" tend to be composed of many different frequencies.

As for changing it, maybe you could look into various sound generation algorithms which you can use to make the pitch vary in terms of multiple sine waves.

Comment: Pure sinusoids are the *least* "strident and harsh" sounds.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "strident" being a technical term, and "harsh" is rather subjective.  I was really talking about the (I think uncontroversial?) idea that sinewaves are generally uncomfortable to listen to, which is really a property of the timbre.  There is a lot of psychophysics research around this sorta of stuff, but you should read my answer as "pure sine wave tones sound ugly".

Comment: Fair enough, Gian.  Continuing to veer off topic into hard-to-define terms, I'll guess that the discomfort comes not from the (trivial) spectral content, but rather from the lack of change.  Any tone whose spectrum and amplitude doesn't change would also sound "unnatural."  A sinusiod with an (even slowly) modulated amplitude or frequency, aka tremolo and vibrato, would sound more "natural."

Comment: Well-said, and a nice addendum to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should emit a 440 Hz sinusoid, rather like the oboe tone that symphony orchestras tune to.

However, "how to make something sound better" is not a well-formed question.  Stack Overflow is for software, not aesthetic judgements.